# Using chrome extension open tab and allow auto login

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In popup.html, I am having one submit button. Clicking on that button, I want to open url in new tab and pass username-password so that user can auto login to the website.

I don't want to use manifest's background and content_script.

I want to do it in normal popup.js which is included in popup.html. Is there any way to do that?

Thank you,
Trupti

Comment: See documentation and examples for chrome.tabs.create and chrome.tabs.executeScript.

Comment: can you please share the link for the same?

Comment: Use google or other search engine, shouldn't take more than a few seconds.

Comment: In documentation they have given basic examples. I googled it and didn't find anything related to my question. After googled only I posted this question here. If you can help me out I would appreciate else thank you so much.

Comment: Those basic examples is all you need: chrome.tabs.create opens a tab, chrome.tabs.executeScript runs a content script in that tab, the content script can access the web page and insert your data (username, password).

Comment: Ok, will try it out..thank you...